# How to call injected method from another aspect in PostSharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

**I'm trying to implement the Observer pattern on a school application using PostSharp.**

The situation is as follows:
I have a Repository that I want to notify each TesterForm (forms that allow manipulation of the data within the Repository) each time a change is made.

This is the aspect I want to use to add the Observable part to my Repository:

```
[Serializable]
class ObservableAspect : InstanceLevelAspect
{
    [IntroduceMember]
    List<TesterForm> LT;

    [IntroduceMember]
    public void notifyChange()
    {
         foreach (TesterForm x in LT)
         {
             x.refreshListBoxBuguri();
         }
    }

    [IntroduceMember]
    public void Subscribe(TesterForm t)
    {
        LT.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Then this aspect applied to every method in Repository that changes the data:

```
[Serializable]
class ObservableNotify : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        ((Repository)args.Instance).notifyChange();
    }
}
```

And then this aspect applied to my TesterForm constructor so it Subscribes to my Repository as soon as it is created:

```
class ObserverAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        ((TesterForm)args.Instance).controller.repository.Subscribe((TesterForm)args.Instance);
    }

}
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is that I have no idea how to call a method that I inject with one aspect, from another aspect (ex: repository.Subscribe from TesterForm) or whether this is even possible.

I have done some research on the PostSharp website, but found no details on such an implementation. Also, Google yielded no useful results.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Additional info: using VS 2013, PostSharp works correctly as I've built other simpler aspects (logging and performance monitoring) that do their job as intended.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

An aspect can access the methods introduced by another aspect using the [[ImportMember]](http://doc.postsharp.net/members) attribute. For this to work correctly the importing aspect must also be an *instance scoped aspect* and you would want to specify the correct order of execution for all the involved aspects.

So, your modified example may look like this:

```
[AspectTypeDependency( AspectDependencyAction.Order,
                       AspectDependencyPosition.Before,
                       typeof( ObservableNotify ) )]
[Serializable]
class ObservableAspect : InstanceLevelAspect
{
    [IntroduceMember( Visibility = Visibility.Public )]
    public void notifyChange()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // other class members...
}

[Serializable]
class ObservableNotify : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    [ImportMember("notifyChange", IsRequired = true, Order = ImportMemberOrder.AfterIntroductions)]
    public Action notifyChangeMethod;

    public override void OnExit( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        notifyChangeMethod();
    }

    object IInstanceScopedAspect.CreateInstance( AdviceArgs adviceArgs )
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    void IInstanceScopedAspect.RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }
}
```

However, you can also go with a solution that looks a bit cleaner - have all the weaving code in the single `ObservableAspect`, and mark the methods with a simple `ObservableNotify` attribute.

```
[Serializable]
class ObservableAspect : InstanceLevelAspect
{
    private void notifyChange()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // This is the OnExit advice that previously was in a separate aspect.
    [OnMethodExitAdvice]
    [MethodPointcut("SelectMethods")]
    public void OnMethodExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        notifyChange();
    }

    // Find all the methods that must be intercepted.
    public IEnumerable<MethodBase> SelectMethods(Type targetType)
    {
        foreach (var methodInfo in targetType.GetMethods())
        {
            if (methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ObservableNotify)).Any())
                yield return methodInfo;
        }
    }
}

class ObservableNotify : Attribute
{
     // This is just a marker attribute used by ObservableAspect.
}
```