# How to introduce new property based on existing property and modify existing one?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp, fody

I am trying to automate [this XmlSerializer workaround pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306579/custom-datetime-xml-serialization/7140219#7140219). *See update below.*

Is it possible to introduce new property based on existing property and modify attributes of existing one using PostSharp (or maybe some other AOP tool) ?

It would be preferable to make this modification at build time.

Sample source property:

```
public class TestType {
  // Original version
  [XmlAttribute()]
  public DateTime ReqDateTime {
      get { return this.reqDateTimeField; }
      set { this.reqDateTimeField = value; }
  }
}
```

Desired result (class declaration omitted):

```
// Modified version
// <original property> = "ReqDateTime"
// <original property> marked as XmlIgnore
// New property with name "<original property>ForXml" is introduced with code as per below
// XmlAttribute moved to the newly introduced <original property>ForXml property with parameter "<original property>" 
[XmlIgnore()]
public DateTime ReqDateTime {
    get { return this.reqDateTimeField;}
    set { this.reqDateTimeField = value;}
}

[XmlAttribute("ReqDateTime")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string ReqDateTimeForXml {
    get { return Common.GetAndFormatDate(this, Common.GetCaller()); }
    set { Common.ParseAndSetDate(this, value, Common.GetCaller()); }
}
```

I have found PostSharp tutorial on introducing members, but no information on (a) how to introduce members with dynamic names and (b) how to move attributes (`[XmlAttribute]` in my case) from existing member to the newly created one.

I do not need an exact solution - just some hints would be enough.

---

**Update:** From further research I can conclude that PostSharp does not support dynamic method naming. Also PostSharpIt cannot remove attribute from existing method.

**So let me reword the problem in yet another approach to solve it:**

1) Inject 10 new properties named `IntroducedProperty0`, `IntroducedProperty1`, ... This seems to be [trivial](http://doc.postsharp.net/code-injections#introducing-methods). Properties are hardcoded.

2) Somehow after/with (1) add attribute `[XmlAttribute("nameOftheOriginalProperty#N")]` to the first M of the `IntroducedPropertyN` where N=0..9 and M<=N. This is kind of dynamic. This is possible when [adding attributes to existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851365/how-to-inject-an-attribute-using-a-postsharp-attribute) (not injected) members. However they say you [cannot add attributes to injected members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187703/2746150).
Rest of the injected methods (from M to N) should be marked as [XmlIgnore].

3) Mark original methods of class with [XmlIgnore].

Maybe this is achievable with Fody?

Comment: What is the problem behind your problem? Maybe a custom serializer, which proper formats `DateTime` would be an better aproach?

Comment: Yeah, writing custom serializer, custom xsd.exe and implemening related wcf would be a better approach. See my other question. The only problem is the amount of coding involved.